# How come Spring Webclient onStatus is not applicable for HttpStatus::is4xxClientError?

Tags: spring, undefined, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, http-error

I've implemented a web client based on the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` artifact.

The code:

```java
// create  client bean to use throughout services
@Bean
public WebClient geoserverWebClient() {
    // to not fall prone to DataBufferLimitException
    final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    final ExchangeStrategies sΩtrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
        .build();
    
    return WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .baseUrl(geoserverURL) 
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString(geoserverBasicAuth.getBytes()))
        .build();
}
```

So far I didn't have any issues with using it like:

```java
// send getMap WMS to geoserver
public Mono<byte[]> getMap(String requestURL){

    return geoserverWebClient
    .get()
    .uri(requestURL)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(byte[].class);
}
```

But if I add the `onStatus` method to it in order to check for HTTP errors, I get the errors: *"The method onStatus(Predicate, Function<ClientResponse,Mono<? extends Throwable>>) in the type WebClient.ResponseSpec is not applicable for the arguments (HttpStatus::is4xxClientError"* for `onStatus` and *"The type HttpStatus does not define is4xxClientError(HttpStatusCode)"* for `HttpStatus`.

```java
// various other imports ...

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

// send getMap WMS to geoserver
public Mono<byte[]> getMap(String requestURL){

    return geoserverWebClient
    .get()
    .uri(requestURL)
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
            error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("API not found")))
    .bodyToMono(byte[].class);
}
```

I've read up on the method and as I'm using Spring Boot version 3.0.5 I don't see why it wouldn't work as documented.

I tried starting with the `Builder` instead but it wouldn't change a bit. I also tried other HTTP errors and even writing out `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus::is4xxClientError`. None of that worked. The only thing I didn't do is instantiate a `HttpStatus` object - but I assume the `.onStatus()` method would get the right object from the `.retrieve()` method.

I considered that perhaps my IDE isn't loading the imports correctly at the moment. I've closed the project, restarted the IDE and reopened the project but to no avail. Even deleting the local .m2 folder wouldn't solve the issue.

Is this a Java/Spring problem or a problem with my IDE (VS Code)?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the gradle/maven project to update all dependencies?

Comment: Yes, but the result/error is the same... Is there something about the `Http` object I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

The type parameter in the Predicate (first argument to `onStatus(...)`) is not of type `org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`, but of type `org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode` (which happens to be an interface that the `HttpStatus` enum implements).

As such, switch the method reference from `HttpStatus::is4xxClientError` to `HttpStatusCode::is4xxClientError`, and the error should go away.